# Spring integration/cloud-stream/cloud-dataflow

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

Our application needs to read from Kafka and use Scatter-Gather/Aggregate pattern to do processing and finally writes to datastore. We are using Spring integration for couple of years and are really comfortable with it. However, we want to leverage Kafka Streams and have questions around Spring integration, spring cloud stream and spring cloud data flow

·         Does spring-integration-kafka supports kafka streams or do i need to use spring-cloud-stream for using them? https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-kafka . Are there any code examples?

·         Is Scatter-Gather/Aggregator pattern supported in spring cloud stream and data flow? Would really appreciate if someone can share examples of how it can be implemented

·         Can we mix and match spring-cloud-stream and spring-integration in one flow? If both the above are not possible, I am thinking more like use steam listener and then pass it to integration flow for using other patterns. Is that advisable?

·

Would really appreciate the guidance from experts. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Artem, Gary can you please help here